# Setup command for logging bot in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a logging bot on discord.py and I want to make a setup command where when they use the command it asks them to mention a channel and all the logging events after that will be sent to the channel he mentioned in the command earlier. Can somebody please tell me a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a way to store the channel-id. Generally, this would be done through a json file or database. Assume `save()` is a function that you have defined elsewhere to save the channel-id. Your command would look like this:

```
@bot.command(name='setup')
async def setupCommand(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel):
    save(channel.id)
    await ctx.send(f"Done! Logging channel has been set to {channel.mention}")
```

Comment: Ok! So how do I save the channel id to the .json file and how do I use it afterwards? Can you please help?

Comment: I managed to store the channel it in a .json file, now how do I use it to send messages to the channel using the channel ID?